# when does the Windows DNS client resolver switch back to the first server?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-10

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd197552(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

I know that the client resolver on W10 switches to the second DNS server after trying and failing with the first server for 1 second. But when does it switch back? I know it does after a restart, but what about during regular operation?
From my findings, Windows doesn't "balance" between servers. It sticks with the first one until the 1 second timeout.

Answer (score 0):

The DNS Client selection of secondary or tertiary responses depends on the number of network adapters, the number of DNS Servers, and if Smart Multi Host Name Resolution is enabled.  If enabled (the default), *all DNS servers are queried in parallel*, and the first response is accepted. If disabled, it does not retry.  Any error *or* a negative response will terminate the query.

https://superuser.com/a/970322/31845
https://superuser.com/questions/969171/multihomed-windows-10-dns-resolution-timeouts

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/dns-client-resolution-timeouts

More information on testing DNS Client settings variations:

https://yogadns.com/docs/interfaces/

https://medium.com/@ValdikSS/beware-of-windows-10-dns-resolver-and-dns-leaks-5bc5bfb4e3f1

https://proprivacy.com/privacy-news/warning-windows-10-vpn-users-big-risk-dns-leak

Comment: Thanks for the throughput answer, but is seems like SMHNR doesn’t query all servers at once, it just queries all protocols at once. Let’s say I have two servers and the resolver drops to the second one because the first is unavailable, after how long would it revert back to the first one?